# Behavior of a complex polynomial at infinity

Tags: complex-analysis, polynomials, infinity

If the real part of a polynomial P(is), where s is real, is always positive, then is it possible for the real part of the polynomial to have negative value as s goes to infinity?

This means that the polynomial never crosses the imaginary axis except possibly at infinity, when the domain is the imaginary axis.

For example,
Re P(z)= z^4 +8z^3 + 3z^2 + 8z + 3, has no zero, when z=is, and s is real. Also P(iR) and P(-IR) both are in the right half plane when R goes to infinity. Will P(iR) and P(-iR) always be in the right half plane for all polynomials, when P(is) is always positive?

Comment: What do you mean the real part is always positive?  Can you give a non-constant  example?

Comment: Suppose P(z) has the domain: the imaginary axis, and further suppose that P(z) has real part always positive. THEN is it possible for P(z) to cross the imaginary axis?

Comment: Please edit your post to include all the assumptions you intended.  Also please provide an example of the sort of situation you have in mind.

Answer (score 1):

If a polynomial $p$ is not constant, then the equation $p(z)=-1$ has a solution, so the real part of any non-constant polynomial cannot be "always positive".